# Remove an element from array and save other duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global array with elements like this and which I have added to keep track of things and which contains duplicate values for counting the number of selection in the code.

```
arrayOfSelectedIds = [a1,a2,a1,a1,a1,a1]
```

I have a function:

```
function deleteSelection()
{
    var valueOfId  = "a1";
    arrayOfSelectedIds.remove(valueOfId);             
}
```

Now I want to remove it only one at a time i.e when the function is called the id value that is present in variable valueOfId should be removed only one time from array.  I want the output should be like

```
arrayOfSelectedIds = [a2,a1,a1,a1,a1]
```

And if  `valueOfId = a2`  then

```
arrayOfSelectedIds = [a1,a1,a1,a1,a1]
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Can you share the error message or the output that you are getting?

Comment: Use Array.prototype.findIndex() or Array.prototype.indexOf() to find first element that satisfies provided function. Then use Array.prototype.splice() method to remove that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

You can use `splice()` like the following way:

```js
var arrayOfSelectedIds = ['a1','a2','a1','a1','a1','a1']

function deleteSelection(valueOfId){
  arrayOfSelectedIds.splice(arrayOfSelectedIds.indexOf(valueOfId), 1);             
}
deleteSelection('a1');
console.log(arrayOfSelectedIds);
```

Comment: Will it preserve other duplicate ids

Comment: @NidaAmin, it will find the first matched item in the array and will only remove that....other duplicate item will be preserved....